# Using Elastic Search Geo Functionality To Find Most Common Locations Ordered By Time

Tags: elasticsearch, geolocation

I currently have a ES query which gives me a list of "geo buckets" using `geohash_grid` and `date_histogram`:

```
  "aggregations": {
"zoomedInView": {
  "filter": {
    "geo_bounding_box": {
      "location": {
        "top_left": "-37, 140",
        "bottom_right": "-38, 146"
      }
    }
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "zoom1": {
      "geohash_grid": {
        "field": "location",
        "precision": 6
      },
      "aggs": {
        "ts": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "min_doc_count" : 1,
            "field": "dateTime",
            "interval": "1m",
            "format": "DDD HH:mm"
          }
         },
         "map_zoom": { 
            "geo_bounds": {
                "field": "location"
            }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which gives me results looking like:

```
{
              "key": "r1r0fu",
              "map_zoom": {
                 "bounds": {
                    "top_left": {
                       "lat": -38.81073913909495,
                       "lon": 124.96536672115326
                    },
                    "bottom_right": {
                       "lat": -38.81329075805843,
                       "lon": 124.96823584660888
                    }
                 }
              },
              "ts": {
                 "buckets": [
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "136 20:15",
                       "key": 1463354100000,
                    },                       
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "137 04:30",
                       "key": 1463365800000,
                       "doc_count": 1
                    },
....

{
              "key": "r1r0gx",
              "map_zoom": {
                 "bounds": {
                    "top_left": {
                       "lat": -38.798130828887224,
                       "lon": 124.99871227890253
                    },
                    "bottom_right": {
                       "lat": -38.79820383526385,
                       "lon": 124.99872468411922
                    }
                 }
              },
              "ts": {
                 "buckets": [
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "136 23:21",
                       "key": 1463354460000,
                    },
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "137 02:30",
                       "key": 1463365800000,
                    },
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "137 03:31",
                       "key": 1463369460000,
                    }
                 ]
              }
           },
```

In the above example the results are ordered by the geo buckets `r1r0fu` and `r1r0gx` and within the buckets the ordered time (in the format day-of-year HHH:mm) of the events and their count.

What I'd really like is:

1) The results ordered by time, which may mean the same buckets will appear multiple times.

2) Only the minimum and maximum time shown within each bucket (if possible)

So the results above would ideally look like:

```
                {
              "key": "r1r0fu",
              "map_zoom": {
                 "bounds": {
                    "top_left": {
                       "lat": -38.81073913909495,
                       "lon": 124.96536672115326
                    },
                    "bottom_right": {
                       "lat": -38.81329075805843,
                       "lon": 124.96823584660888
                    }
                 }
              },
              "ts": {
                 "buckets": [
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "136 20:15",
                       "key": 1463354100000,
                    },
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "r1r0gx",
              "map_zoom": {
                 "bounds": {
                    "top_left": {
                       "lat": -38.798130828887224,
                       "lon": 124.99871227890253
                    },
                    "bottom_right": {
                       "lat": -38.79820383526385,
                       "lon": 124.99872468411922
                    }
                 }
              },
              "ts": {
                 "buckets": [
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "136 23:21",
                       "key": 1463354460000,
                    },                
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "137 03:31",
                       "key": 1463369460000,
                    },  
                }
            },
            {
              "key": "r1r0fu",
              "map_zoom": {
                 "bounds": {
                    "top_left": {
                       "lat": -38.81073913909495,
                       "lon": 124.96536672115326
                    },
                    "bottom_right": {
                       "lat": -38.81329075805843,
                       "lon": 124.96823584660888
                    }
                 }
              },
              "ts": {
                 "buckets": [
                    {
                       "key_as_string": "137 04:30",
                       "key": 1463365800000,
                    }
                ]
              }
            },
            ...
```

Where the results are ordered by time so the bucket `r1r0fu` appears twice in this case. And the event `"key_as_string": "137 02:30",` has been hidden as it is not the minimum or maximum date.

Is this anyway possible?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the results ordered by time, maybe it'd be better to swap the `date_histogram` aggregation with the `geohash_grid` one, like this:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "zoomedInView": {
      "filter": {
        "geo_bounding_box": {
          "location": {
            "top_left": "-37, 140",
            "bottom_right": "-38, 146"
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "ts": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "field": "dateTime",
            "interval": "1m",
            "format": "DDD HH:mm"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "zoom1": {
              "geohash_grid": {
                "field": "location",
                "precision": 6
              }
            },
            "map_zoom": {
              "geo_bounds": {
                "field": "location"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That would take care of the question 1). However, since now each main bucket will be a time bucket, you won't be able to have the min and max time anymore. Try it out and see if it works for your needs.

Comment: Hi Val! Thanks for the speedy reply. Yes that works great! Now the same geo hash maybe output several times consecutively for all times between the min and max time. I only need the min and max time for each geo hash if that's possible to reduce the amount of data returned and to transverse in the consumer?

Comment: You can either bucket by geohash+date (in which case you cannot sort the geohash buckets by dates) or by date+geohash (in which case you cannot get min/max date per geohash), but not mix/match both. You probably need to go with your initial solution and sort on the client-side.